# Android drawer navigation dark mode with transparent status bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-dark-theme

I use navigation drawer in my app and I try to implement dark theme. When the app doesn't cover the whole screen and the status bar isn't transparent the *navigationView* is automatically colored to dark. But when the app covers the whole screen and the status bar is transparent the *navigationView* stays white. How can I force the *navigationView* to be dark even when the app covers the whole screen and status bar is transparent?

I don't explicitily set the background color or the text color, it uses the default values.

[image: This is how it behaves]

The layout code looks like this:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<!-- Some other views wrapped in RelativeLayout -->

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/mainnav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/mainmenu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/mainmenu_header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:insetForeground="@null">

        <include android:id="@+id/mainmenuheader"
            layout="@layout/mainmenu_header"/>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The style that the activity uses to make it fullscreen with transparent status bar looks like this:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

And finally in the manifest for the activity a apply the theme and set the *fitsSystemWindows* to true:

```
<activity
    android:name=".map.MapActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="uiMode"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"         
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
```

Comment: What you have done code so for ?

Comment: I edited the question and added the code I use